# Uninstall XAMPP in linux mint

Tags: xampp, linux-mint

I have **deleted the lampp folder from /opt/** directory and tried restarting the pc too but still http://localhost/dashboard/ is showing xampp dashboard.

How do I uninstall xampp completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last night I turned off my pc and went to sleep. Now I have sat to work on this problem and re-[installed lampp](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu) and amazingly http://localhost/dashboard/ shows **404 Not Found**.

So yes my problem is solved,somehow.

P.S : I have not deleted the question/answered it myself so that anyone facing this dilaema like me might get help.